# Blender Editing Mode is Too Slow Even With a Simple Model

Tags: edit-mode

Here is the video about the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4YFtXEG6Bs

Basically if I make a cut with CTRL + R, the edge moves like 2 fps. And other edges moves like 5 fps. 
I tried to work just with CPU or with my RX 570, results is same.

Do you guys any idea? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the subdivision surface modifier for the edit mode?

Comment: Yes, it helps but what is the point then? I need it. What should I do?